# Systemctl command getting this error: Failed to et D-bus: Unkknown error -1 | Docker Opensuse

Tags: linux, docker, systemd, docker-container, systemctl

In **opensuse docker container**, **cronjob is not working**. When I try ***systemctl*** command getting this error: **Failed to et D-bus: Unknown error -1** . I have tried many blogs and stackoverflow questions everywhere It was advised that basic architecture of Docker image should be redesigned.

**What exactly  needs to be done here is not mentioned. Kindly help, I am stuck on this issue.**

Comment: personally I would avoid using cronjobs inside any container as the historic benefits of a cron are supplanted by the notion of a container itself  ... if you need something container friendly I suggest using supervisord to be the parent of children processes launched inside a container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To a first approximation, commands like `systemctl`, `initctl`, `service`, or `start` just don't work in Docker and you should find a different way to do what you're attempting.

Stylewise, the standard way to use a Docker container is to launch some sort of service *in the foreground*.  As one specific example, the [standard Redis image](https://github.com/docker-library/redis/blob/53f86805506b103b503fd392e029929290fe5346/4.0/Dockerfile#L83) doesn't go through any sort of init script; it just runs

```
CMD ["redis-server"]
```

In most Docker images it's unusual to even so much as launch a background process (with the shell `&` operator).  It's not usually necessary and in Dockerfiles the interaction with the `RUN` directive has confused some people.

In the specific case of `systemctl`, it requires an extremely heavyweight init system that is not just a process manager but also wants to monitor and manage kernel-level parameters, includes a logging system, runs an inter-process message bus, and some other functionality.  You can't run systemd under Docker without the container being `--privileged`, which gives the container the ability to "escape" on to the host system in some unfortunate ways.